# What is the meaning of "Some days are two sizes too small"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sanderson is waiting for Paul to began the meeting, so Paul arrived & Sanderson welcoming him.

> Sanderson: There he is. Paul, come in.
>
> Paul: Sorry. There were unexpected developments. I had to go home and
>   start the day again.
>
> Sanderson: Tell me about it. **Some days are two sizes too small**.

I didn't understand What Sanderson said to Paul about Days?

Comment: Think of clothing that's two sizes too small.  You couldn't fit yourself into it.  A day two sizes too small is a metaphor.  It would be a day in which you had too many things you had to do to fit it in one day.

Comment: I dont think that this is a common expression. I've never heard it or seen it, so perhaps Sanderson was being original. But I like it very much.

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that some times a day/24 hours seems too small/less for all the tasks we require to complete on that day.